# Finding complexities of space and time using recursion

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

first function:-

```
void strange (int n,int k)

 {

int i;

if(k > n)

return;

for(i=k; i<n; i++)
  printf("?");

strange(n, k+2);
return;
}
```

second function:-

```
void weird(int n, int k)
{

int i;

if(n <= 0 || (k <= 0))
   return;

k *=2;

for(i=0; i < k; i++){

  printf("?");

  weird(n/2, -n/2 )
}
weird(n/2, k)

return;
}
```

Im having a hard time with finding the complexities of both space or time for both of these functions.I know that I have to use recursion here but I just dont understand recursion. Im new to this and my teacher just doesnt explain very well.Is there a simple way to calculate both the complexities of space and time using recursion?
and can you give me a hint in how to approach questions from this kind?

NOTE:- Im not asking for full answer just hints and advice.So Please dont misunderstand this post.

Comment: Congratulations on asking for advice rather than a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use recursion to find the complexities, you need to find the complexities within the recursion. I think if I clarify a couple things, you'll see what you need to do.

**Recursion**

First off, recursion is simply a function that calls itself. Pretty straightforward. A really simple recursive function could be used for counting:

```
recursiveCounter(current, max)
{
  if(current > max)
    return;

  printf("%i ", current);
  recursiveCounter(current + 1, max);
}
```

This function will keep calling itself until current is greater than max, then it returns.

**Complexities**

Now, as far as your complexities go, you have two; space, and time. Space is how much memory you need w/ respect to your input, while time is how many iterations your function will perform. In my example, the space complexity is *O(1)* (this is constant), while my time complexity would be *O(N)* (linearly increasing).

Another example:

```
recursiveCounter2(current, max)
{
  if(current >= max)
    return;

  for(int x = 0; x < max; ++X)
  {
    printf("%i ", current);
  }

  printf("\n");

  recursiveCounter(current + 1, max);
}
```

This function will count to the given number from scratch each time. Output would look like the following:

```
max = 5
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
```

And so on.

**Putting It Together**

So, break it down into parts:

**Q.** How many times will my recursive function be called?

**A.** Because of my comparison `(current < max)` and my linear growth `(current + 1)`,    we can assume it will run `max` amount of times.

---

**Q.** How many times will I iterate *inside* the function?

**A.** The for loop will also perform `max` number of operations.

Factoring this all together, we will perform `max * max` computations. That makes this an *O(N^2)* algorithm. Therefore, if max is 5, we have 5 * 5 = 25 computations.

Breaking your problems down piece by piece is the best way to approach this.

Comment: What is the complexity of space in your second example because I think its O(1)?

Comment: Still constant, yes. These aren't really good examples of algorithms since they don't really do anything, but they're good for concepts. Most algorithms have space complexities of O(1) or O(N). A favorite website of mine is [this algorithm cheat sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**First function:**

You are running a loop from k to n, which in the worst case would start at 0 to n (Assuming k and n are always positive).

With every recursion, you are moving two integers closer to completion, running the loop two times less than the last. This only adds a constant multiplier to the complexity.

So essentially, for a worst case scenario, you are running the loop n times, then n-2 times, then n-4 times, and so on. k does not have an impact on the time complexity. If at all, it reduces the running time but big-Oh notation discards this.

**Second function:**

The for loop runs k times. The function within the for loop is useless as it will return on the if condition once called (-ve value of k).

n is reduced to half every recursion. To calculate the time complexity for such a recursion, you can consider it like 
T(n) = T(n/2) and T(1) = 1

i.e. The time it takes to run the recursion with the value n is the same as the time it takes to run the recursion with the value n/2. And when n reduces to 1, it is a O(1) execution.

Solve the recursive equation to get the time complexity of the recursion calls.

The time complexity of the function itself would be the product of the time complexity of the for loop and the time complexity of the recursion.

**Space complexity:**
Both functions only have integer variables. No arrays/strings.